# Ошибка при работе с ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql

При работе с ADO.NET возникла какая то ошибка. Код выполняется, а данных из базы нет. Если в брэкмоинте посмотреть переменную reader, то можно увидеть поле Results View со значением "Перечисление не дало результатов". Подскажите в чём проблема?

```
public void GetAllKatNumDir(string katNumDir)
{
    string connectionString ="data source=DataBase; Initial Catalog = products; Integrated Security = False; User ID = User; Password = 123123";

    string queryString = "SELECT KatNamDirectory.KatNumDir, Main.designationRU FROM dbo.KatNamDirectory INNER JOIN dbo.Main ON KatNamDirectory.id = Main.Kat WHERE KatNamDirectory.KatNumDir = @KutNum";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        // Create the Command and Parameter objects.
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KutNum", katNumDir);

        // Open the connection in a try/catch block. 
        // Create and execute the DataReader, writing the result
        // set to the console window.
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: А Вы пробовали в самой базе данных выполнять этот запрос с таким же параметром? Он возвращает какие-либо результаты?

Comment: да, в Managment Studio всё выполняется

Comment: В переменную `katNumDir` нормальное значение передается?

Comment: @Vlad если там выполняется то почему невыполняется из кода? Неплохо бы еще и ридер запустить после `SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();` напишите `while(reader.Read()){а тут уже разбор ридера }`

Comment: с ридором заработало!

Comment: Только я почему то думал что данные должны быть видны в Results View переменной reader. Видимо это не так

Comment: метод Read() читает строчку из контекста запроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

после

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

напишите

```
 while(reader.Read()){а тут уже разбор ридера }
```